# Sticky header responsive issues

Tags: javascript, css, sidebar, sticky

I'm trying to create a sticky sidebar. It's working fine in desktop resolutions but unfortunately not working in responsive resolutions. And also the sticky bar should stick top of the content in mobile resolutions instead of left as in the desktop resolutions.
For more clarifications I'm attaching my js and css files here.
http://dev.netbramha.in/projects/sticky-header/index.js
http://dev.netbramha.in/projects/sticky-header/style.css

Can you guys please help me?

```html
<header>
  Header
</header>
<main>
  <div class="center">
    <div class="fullwidth">
      Full Width Block
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="left-sidebar">
        <div class="content">
          Sticky Sidebar
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="main-content">
        Main Content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fullwidth two">
      Full Width Block
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<footer>
  Footer
</footer>
```

Comment: Can you insert a working snippet of what you are trying to explain?

Comment: You can explain more by inserting relavant sample images

Answer (score 1):

for the responsive issue you need to [css media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp) 
otherwise, you can use [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) (css framework ) thats automatically doing responsive on your website

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .left-sidebar .main-content{
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<header>
    Header
</header>
<main>
    <div class="center">
        <div class="fullwidth">
            Full Width Block
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="left-sidebar">
                <div class="content">
                    Sticky Sidebar
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="main-content">
                Main Content
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fullwidth two">
            Full Width Block
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
<footer>
    Footer
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) like below. Hope this helps.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.left-sidebar {
  width: 30%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  .row {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .left-sidebar {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  Header
</header>
<main>
  <div class="center">
    <div class="fullwidth">
      Full Width Block
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="left-sidebar">
        <div class="content">
          Sticky Sidebar
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="main-content">
        Main Content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="fullwidth two">
      Full Width Block
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<footer>
  Footer
</footer>
```